# How do I wear my badge (work tag) on my trousers?

Tags: security

I wear my badge (work tag with embedded RFID identification chip) around my neck, but I see some people have it mounted to the upper part of the trouser. I would like to do that, but I don't know how.

I can't go and ask my friends who follow that style. Is there something I should buy? Or make?

Comment: "I can't go and ask from my friends who follow that style". Why not? What kind of friends do you have that you cannot ask "hey, cool, how did you do this?".

Comment: I don't see the problem with this question in its current form.  I knew exactly what he was asking about and would have offered the same answer Jane did if she hadn't beaten me to it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

[image]

It's called a [badge reel](https://www.eidbadges.com/spring-clip-reels.htm).  A lot of the guys I worked previously with use them by clipping one of these to their belts.  There's a retractable cord so they can swipe access to buildings, etc.

As far as if it's professional, I'd say probably 70% of men used them in my last job (large government department, they mostly wore suits).  You can probably request one from your HR or admin department.  If they don't like you using them, they'll say no :)

Comment: yes exactly.  Sorry , but I expect more, the correct position for it. Step by step guideline to wear it.

Comment: Umm, you clip it on your belt where you can reach it.  Most guys seem to wear it to the side next to the belt loops.  The card attaches through the plastic clippy thingy.  It's really not rocket science :)

Comment: I have it clipped to my pant pocket because I don't like the feeling of something poking my hip bone. That also has the advantage of that it's hanging lower and will not be hidden by upper body clothing (read: shirt) that's not stuck in the pants.

Comment: @simbabque Doesn't that damage the fabric on your pants?  That's why I never clipped it to any of my skirts and just used a lanyard instead.

Comment: @sandundhammika If I wear a dress, unless it has a belt or something then I couldn't use this without pinching the fabric.  Most of my slacks and skirts don't have belts either, which is why most other women I worked with did the same as me and used a lanyard.   You could perhaps attach felt to the inside of the alligator clip so it doesn't have those sharp points to damage your clothes.

Comment: Ours looks more like a paper clip. Just a piece of metal. No crocodile teeth on it. I agree that I wouldn't clip this to my clothes either.

Comment: I use one of these when I visit our main office (local office doesn't require it).  I put the clip through a belt loop, so the metal isn't against my skin *or* the fabric of my pants.  This seems to be the norm at my workplace.

Answer (score 1):

Just another viewpoint on this. It's worth consulting your company procedures/managers. If the tag you're using is just to let you access certain areas, etc. then that's fine, but if it's also got identification on it, it may be that the tag needs to be visible around your neck for security checks and the like.

A number of compliance schemes require employees to be easily distinguishable, and that's usually done by distinctive lanyards and badges. It may be that you get into trouble for wearing it on your trousers rather than around your neck.

Comment: Yep, that's why I said for the OP to request it from HR rather than sourcing it independently.  They can then tell the OP if it's permitted or not :)